# Store resized photo and send email same time in Laravel7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm studying contact from. Laravel Framework is 7.15.0
It works fine.
And I have a question that I would like to add image file attach function.
I wrote like this below currently.

> blade file

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputfile">
</div>
```

> Controller

```
\Mail::send('mail', array(
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'message' => $request->get('message'),
    'inputfile' => $request->get('inputfile'),
), function($message) use ($request){
    $message->from($request->email);
    $message->to('123@testmail.com', 'mail-recive')->subject($request->get('mail-recive'));
});
```

This code stores data at MySQL and send email same time.

And Could you teach me resize function too?
I would like to set maximum size is 2000 x 2000 px.
Could you teach me right code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to restrict a user not to upload an image more than a specific size e.g 3mb, you can do it with [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-size) and if you're looking for image dimensions resizing, there is an awesome package [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) for it. And it works well with laravel. You can do more than just resizing an image with this package.

Here is an example, how you can resize your image:

```
if($request->hasFile('img')){
    $img = Image::make($request->img);
    
    $img->resize(500, 500);

    $img->save('Your/Public/Path/image.jpg');
}
```

You easily find how to install and use this package in [official documentation](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me. Do me a favor could you add to my current code? I still don't get how to add your code.

Comment: @bluetail Do this before you send Mail and attach the resized file in your `'inputfile' => $img->response('jpg');`. It's simple just read the documentation, how to install intervention and you'll be doing it in no time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still couldn't figure out. I will take a look document.

Comment: @bluetail You're welcome! It's really easy you just have to implement and test. Keep testing you'll learn a lot that way and ultimately achieve what you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel medaialibrary  for work with medias such as images you can use this link [medialibrary doc](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v8/introduction)